# Operation not supported for specified element type

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am getting this error in an eclipse plugin. Here is the code :

```
ICompilationUnit testCU = findTestUnit(type);
// add some stuff to testCU
testCU.commitWorkingCopy(false, null);    // error happens here.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess that you're using [this interface](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit.java.htm).  Here's the method signature in question:

```
void commitWorkingCopy(boolean force, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws JavaModelException;
```

Perhaps you can try casting that `null` to `IProgressMonitor`.

Another idea would be to look at the type returned by that method call and make sure that it implements the right interface.  Perhaps that is not correct.

Comment: I am not getting `NullPointerException`.